# Can't call JavaScript Function from JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, call

I am trying to call my `JavaScript Function` from my `jQuery Function`, but it does not seem to be calling the function `showMain()` at the end of the jQuery.

See below: I am trying to Call the `showMain()` function at the end of the `.click` function.
Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
        $('.slideshowExit').click(function () {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#welcomeText").fadeOut(2000);
                },1000);
            $("#welcomePage").css("display", "none");

            //The function I am trying to Call
            showMain();
            });    




    function showMain() {
        var main= document.getElementById("mainDiv");
        main.style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: make fiddle, or post HTML as well

Comment: Define function before calling from jquery

Comment: But showMain should be hoisted (function hoisting).

Comment: It should work..Look at the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bLjLz0m5/1/ In your case it is not working because of other conditions or errors

Comment: Just cleanup and align your code correctly and you'll see the errors by yourself.

Comment: @DEFALT You should use power of console and see the errors carefully

Answer (score 4):

You should use an anonymous function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slideshowExit').click(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#welcomeText").fadeOut(2000);
        }, 1000);
        $("#welcomePage").css("display", "none");

        //The function I am trying to Call
        showMain();
    });
});


var showMain = function () {
    var main = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
    main.style.display = 'block';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake with your function definition. Please use the closing `"}"` bracket after the function.

I am trying to call my JavaScript Function from my jQuery Function, but it does not seem to be calling the function `showMain()` at the end of the jQuery.

See below: I am trying to Call the `showMain()` function at the end of the `.click` function. Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $('.slideshowExit').click(function () {
       setTimeout(function() {
       $("#welcomeText").fadeOut(2000);
    },1000);

    $("#welcomePage").css("display", "none");
    //The function I am trying to Call
    showMain();
 });    

function showMain() {
    var main= document.getElementById("mainDiv");
    main.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Runnable Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slideshowExit').click(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#welcomeText").fadeOut(500);
        }, 1000);
        $("#welcomePage").css("display", "none");

        //The function I am trying to Call
        showMain();
    });
})



    function showMain() {
        var main = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
        main.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slideshowExit">
  Click Here
</div>

<div id="mainDiv">
  <div id="welcomeText">Welcome to India</div>
</div>
```